# Need to see if character is in array but not in same position as other array c++

Tags: c++

I'm making a wordle in C++ and I need to check two char arrays against each other to see if the letter in one is in the other one but not in the same position, here's my code so far, the second if in the for loop is where I need help (its going to be colored that's the reason for the constants and the color codes):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const string CORRECT = "\033[7;32m";
const string CLOSE = "\033[7;33m";
const string INCORRECT = "\033[7;37m";
const string END = "\033[0m";
int main() {
  char word[] = "break";
  char guess[] = "water";
  char result[5];
  string color;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (guess[i] != word[i])
      {
        color = INCORRECT + guess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color
      }

    if (guess[i] != word[i] && )
      {
        color = CLOSE + guess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color
      }

    if (guess[i] == word[i])
      {
        color = CORRECT + guess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color
      }

  }

  return 0;

}
```

I've got it to where it checks to see if its not the same position but I need it to also check for it being elsewhere in the char array. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `std::find`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

...

if (guess[i] != word[i] && std::find(word, word+5, guess[i]) != word + 5)
  {
    ..
  }
```

See [`std::find` in cppreference doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: i tried that and i gave me an error: ```error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘word’, which is of non-class type ‘char [6]```

Comment: there will ever only be 5 items in the char array so i just checked guess[i] against every position in word[].

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought that `guess` and `word` were `std::string` type, not `char array` type. I updated my answer.